# MTM Lab Center cannot add new Machines

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, mtm

[image: Cannot Add New Machines]

I'm trying to set up a new lab environment in MTM (2010) in TFS 2010 for a client.  When I attempt to define a new environment I get to this screen and everything is disabled.   Is this a permissions issue or perhaps was it TFS was not set up with Lab Environment?

Should I be able to add a machine?  If I go to the test settings tabs, I get to the "Roles" section and it tells me there are no Test Environments, when I click the link it takes me back to this screen below.

We were able to create the controller yesterday and it shows up in the Controllers tab.

Experimenting futher on this tab I attempt to "Componse Virtual Environment" and this is the message it showed. "You cannot create a Virtual Environment"

[image: Cannot create virtual Environment]

I am not TFS Admin, and need to ask someone else to do this if indeed it's the issue. I'll look it up on google but am also looking for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that I didn't know, at the time; when clicking on the "Machines" tab that you must highlight the controller and then click "Add to the Environment" once I did that I saw the machine pop up in the Environments window.

Comment: Also, when configuring the Test Agent the controller name is the name of the computer you have installed the controller.  That part is not implicit when setting up the controller because there is no name field.  The "network service" account will work when you the computer is in the same domain as TFS...  We were unable to get out of domain controllers to work....